# OSIV:false , cannot get session for resolving FetchType.Lazy items, even in the scope of @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

In my spring application, I have disabled osiv (spring.jpa.open-in-view=false) to avoid holding hibernate sessions throughout a request lifecycle.

After disabling OSIV, I am getting the following error when I try to access a field in my entity that has the `FetchType` set as `LAZY`

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [sg.identity.auth.entity.OrganizationEntity#2] - no Session
```

This is the entity I'm using and I'm trying to access userEntity.getOrganization() which results in the LazyInitializationException.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"USER\"")
public class UserEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "organization_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_id"))
    private OrganizationEntity organization;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_parent_organization_unit_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organization_unit_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_unit_id"))
    private Set<OrganizationUnitEntity> organizationUnits;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_exclusion_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "excluding_permission_set_id", referencedColumnName = "permission_set_id"))
    private PermissionSetEntity exclusionPermissions;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles;

}
```

I'm calling the user.getOrganizationEntity in a method annotated with @Transactional so It should receive an open session to resolve the lazy items. But in my case, it is not working

```java
 @Transactional
 public Organization getOrganization(String emailId) {
     return userRepository.getUserByEmailId(emailId)
             .map(UserEntity::getOrganization)
             .map(OrganizationMapper::toDto)
             .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("error"));
 }
```

The user.getOrganization is resolving correctly when I try using `TransactionTemplate`.

```java
    @Transactional
    public Organization getOrganization(String emailId) {
        return transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            return userRepository.getUserByEmailId(emailId)
                    .map(UserEntity::getOrganization)
                    .map(OrganizationMapper::toDto)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("error"));
        });
    }
```

---

I got it working with @Transactional itself by setting the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`, but from my research, i found that it is not recommended to set this flag as true

Comment: It depends on from where you call the `getOrganization` if this is an internal method call the `@Transactional` is useless. The fact that it works with a `TransactionTemplate` indicates this as well. That being said instead of getting the `User` to get the `Organization` why not directly return the `Organization` from the database, that will save you a query.